# Generate replacement

Tags: arrays, loops

How can I generate different combinations of the word "password" and it can include upper and lower case and both 'S' characters can be replaced with 5 and the 'o' character can be replaced with the number 0

eg Results:

> Password 
>   p@s5word 
>   pa5sWord 
>   pa55w0rd 
>   PAssw0rd 
>   etc

Any help will be appreciated

This is what I have so far, but only returns the same string of "ppassword"

```
char[] CharList = new char[] 
       {'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','@','5','5','0','P','A','S','S','W','O','R','D'};
string password = "password";
int _base = CharList.Length;

int current = IntPasswordsGenerated++;

do
{
    password = CharList[current % _base] + password;
    current /= _base;
} while (current != 0);

return password;
```

Comment: Permutation: the act of changing the order of elements arranged in a particular order, as abc into acb, bac, etc., or of arranging a number of elements in groups made up of equal numbers of the elements in different orders, as a and b in ab and ba; a one-to-one transformation of a set with a finite number of elements.
What you are trying do is called string replacement

Comment: I tried some code I found which uses a Char array that can be used but that only returned the same string everytime : ppassword. I'm hitting a brick wall

Comment: @EthanJappie So show us what you did so far. Any signs of effort.

Comment: @Tinwor , thank you for clearing that up, makes much more sense

Comment: You are welcome, take a look to leet "alphabet" it may help

Comment: This is what I had but only returns the same string.char[] CharList = new char[] {'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d','@','5','5','0','P','A','S','S','W','O','R','D'};
            string password = "password";
            int _base = CharList.Length;

            int current = IntPasswordsGenerated++;

            do
            {
                password = CharList[current % _base] + password;
                current /= _base;
            } while (current != 0);

            return password;

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41139487/edit) button to update your question

Comment: Why would you think that would work? You need multiple list of leet replacement for each normal digit/letter, iterate each password character and randomly select the appropriate replacement.

Comment: @Tinwor You are a star, this helps so much

Comment: @Mong Zhu Thank for editing the post, I am very new to this so I struggled with the formatting

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I have an idea for that. I rebuild simple "permutation" function and made it use a custom list of objects instead of pure `char` :

```
    public class CharData
    {
        char[] _char= new char[0];
        public char[] Characters { get { return _char; } set { _char= value; } }
    }

// method to initialize character data
    public static List<CharData> Initialize() 
    {
        List<CharData> charData = new List<CharData>();
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 'p', 'P' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 'a', 'A' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 's', 'S', '5' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 's', 'S', '5' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 'w', 'W' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 'o', 'O', '0' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 'r', 'R' }
        });
        charData.Add(new CharData {
            Characters = new char[] { 'd', 'D' }
        });
        // Add your characters in order you want them to be processed
        return charData;
    }

// rebuilded permutation 
    public static void Build(List<CharData> data, string build = "", int startingIndex = -1) 
    {
        if( build.Length == data.Count )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(build);
        }
        else
        {
            for ( int i = startingIndex + 1; i < data.Count; i ++ )
            {
                for ( int j = 0; j < data[i].Characters.Length; j++)
                {
                    Build(data, build + data[i].Characters[j], i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Build(Initialize());
    }
```

[Test it on rextester](http://rextester.com/BPLW39986)

Answer (score 1):

Side Note: As Tinwor mentioned this a char replacement not permutation.

So, here is one way to do it:

1. Build a set of lists that contain possible replacement chars for each 'unique' character in the word you are interested in this case its 'password';
2. Write a function that accepts a word to operate on and the lists or replacement chars;

A quick sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<char, List<char>> _replacementChars = new Dictionary<char, List<char>>{};

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Fill replacement chars collection
        _replacementChars.Add('p', new List<char>{'p', 'P'});
        _replacementChars.Add('a', new List<char>{'a', 'A', '4'});
        _replacementChars.Add('s', new List<char>{'s', 'S', '$', '&', '5'});
        _replacementChars.Add('w', new List<char>{'w', 'W'});
        _replacementChars.Add('o', new List<char>{'o', 'O', '0', '@'});
        _replacementChars.Add('r', new List<char>{'r', 'R', '4'});
        _replacementChars.Add('d', new List<char>{'d', 'D'});

        // We want to search on lower variants of each char of the source word, beacuase it's simple this way
        var sourceWord = "password".ToLower();

        var sourceWordChars = sourceWord.ToCharArray();
        var targetWordChars = new char[sourceWord.Length];

        // TODO: This will need a different implementation if we want to get all possible variations of the sourceWord rather than just a random version of it 
        for(var i = 0; i < sourceWordChars.Length; i++)
        {
            var replacement = GetReplacementChar(sourceWordChars[i]);

            targetWordChars[i] = replacement;
        }

        var targetWord = string.Join("", targetWordChars);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Source word: {0}", sourceWord));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Target word: {0}", targetWord));
    }

    private static char GetReplacementChar(char charToReplace)
    {
        if(!_replacementChars.ContainsKey(charToReplace))
        {
            return charToReplace;
        }

        var chars = _replacementChars[charToReplace];

        // Get random char from list
        var rand = new Random();
        var index = rand.Next(0, chars.Count);

        return chars[index];
    }
}
```

Here is [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AJkssT) for code above.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense from what I originally had

Comment: :) I hope someone will contribute a different solution as well. It would be cool to see other approaches.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder  Interesting edits. You need some extra rep?

Comment: @Alex I removed the noise from your answer, either way as I have more than 2000 rep I don't get any for edits anymore

Comment: @TheLethalCoder In my opinion 'noise' as you put it, is what makes this site a pleasure to visit every day. Making this place cold and faceless is not a good thing. Don't really have any particular emotional attachment to my noise...just my 2 cents as it were.

Comment: At the TODO, what kind of different implementation do you suggest to get all the possible variants of the word?

Comment: That's a difficult question probably worthy of a question of it's own. The thing is that you would need to approach the problem differently. You will need to calculate every possible combination of available replacements and then simply go through the list and select the characters based on your combination.

Comment: @EthanJappie I'll give it a shot later and post an edit.